# Which binary operation does this mapping?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to think of the binary operation that would map

```
1100
0101
to
1000
```

That is, the resulting bit is only 1 if the first bit was 1 and the second was 0;
I'm completly stuck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us mark the first row as A and the second row as B.
Thus you're looking for `A * !B`.

Meaning: A and not B. Let us look in your example:

```
A | B | !B | A*(!B)
1 | 0 | 1  |   1
0 | 1 | 0  |   0
0 | 0 | 1  |   0
0 | 1 | 0  |   0
```

In general, I would suggest writing down what you want it to do:

> resulting bit is only **1** if the first bit was **1** **and** the second was **0**

Meaning: 1 AND not the other.

Hope this helps :)

P.S. Hope you're not referring to a single binary operation.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful :)